# Print option not accepting the job name

Tags: android, android-webview, android-print-framework

I am trying to print a web page. i used the below code to print the webview. when clicks the print button, it opens the webpage in pdf but the name i passed is not displaying. it showing like default.pdf. how to name the pdf?

```
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
          .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = 
             webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + 
                        " Print Test";

    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
           new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

but i saw in chrome print option, they can able to pass the name for PDF. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?